# Where to put Action Script in Flash, to be called just once on the beginning?

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

I have a Flash app where I call the first frame over and over. I have a script, that I need to be executed just once at the beginning. Where should i put it? Obvioulsy the first frame isn't a good idea, the script is called to many times. Is there some place for this or some function that would allow me do this?

Thanks

Comment: if your entire flash app is one frame, this shouldn't loop - flash just calls it once - not loop over and over again.

Comment: no it's not. I have many frames, but most of them go back to frame 1

Answer (score 0):

I would put it on the first frame and just keep a variable that check to see if the code had been run the first time around, and if it has been, don't run the code. Post your code though, that'll be helpful.

Maybe a function would be good so we can static the load variable

```
static var firstLoad:Boolean;
checkLoad();
public function checkLoad(){
if(firstLoad)
{
//run loaded script
}else{
//run first time script
firstLoad = true;
}
}
```

Comment: I tried that. The problem is following: I need to define the variable first. So I have to write something like firstLoad = true and this code will be run over and over again so firstLoad will be always true. I don't believe code would be very helpful though - I just set several variables like score = 0. And I of course don't want the score to be always 0

Comment: the compiler tells me that static was declared out of class... I'm using actionscript2. Are there any differences that would make this code wrong?

Comment: Many.  In fact, my answer above won't help you if you're using AS2.  The question should be retagged to make that explicit.

Answer (score 0):

**Will not work for the OP's situation, as OP is using AS2.  This is an AS3 way to handle it.**

In the constructor of the class definition.  Make a class file for the MovieClip and just do whatever you need to do in the constructor function like so.

```
// in a file called "Foo.as" (replace Foo with whatever you want the classname to be)
package /*your package goes here, if any*/ {

    import flash.display.MovieClip;

    // The class name should be identical to the name of the file, minus the .as extention
    public class Foo extends MovieClip{

        // the function name of the constructor is identical to the Class name as well as the file's name minus the .as extention.


        public function Foo(){

            // This code only happens one time.

        }

    }
}
```

Just use that as your class linkage for the movieclip that only needs to execute the script "one time."